# Custom allocator without pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++, c++11, allocator, pointer-arithmetic

I have a custom allocator class which looks something like this:

```
class allocator {
private:
  char* memory;
  std::ptrdiff_t offset;
  std::size_t total_size;

public:
  allocator(std::size_t size) : total_size(size), offset(0) {
    memory = new char[size];
  }
  void* allocate(std::size_t size, std::size_t alignment) {
    // unimportant stuff

    void* current_address = &start_ptr[offset]; // --> OUCH, pointer arithmethic

    offset += size;
    // unimportant stuff
    return current_address;
  }

}
```

As you can see above I'm using pointer arithmetic to calculate the current address for the newly allocated block of memory. The [CppCoreGuidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#r2-in-interfaces-use-raw-pointers-to-denote-individual-objects-only) and many other guidelines discourage the use of pointer arithmethic. So is there another way of managing the memory pool?

I was thinking of maybe using a `std::vector<char>`, as it contains a contiguous block of memory, and doing something like this:

```
std::vector<char> memory;

void* current_address = &(memory.at(offset));
```

But this doesn't seem any nicer to me. Do you have any ideas of how to cleanly manage the memory pool in a safe way?

Comment: They discourage pointer arithmetic for "standard" operations. Dealing with uninitialized storage allocation is not. IMO, pointer arithmetic in an allocator's allocate function is perfectly fine if its simple to read.

Comment: I could argue that `&(memory.at(offset))` is just disguised pointer arithmetic .  Put it in a function call and all is ok?  So if calling `at` is ok just write your own wrapper function.

Comment: I don't see that the guidance you linked to bans all pointer arithmetic. Things like memory allocators are hard to write without using it.

Comment: If it's the CppCoreGuidelines that you're concerned about, holding either the entire allocation, or the remaining space, in a `gsl::span` might be a decent choice. Then you'll at least get some extra debugging range checks. Here's what I was thinking: https://godbolt.org/g/aQjDBh
You can decide whether that's an improvement over pointer arithmetic or not.

Comment: Ok, the consensus is that's ok for this kind of implementation.

Comment: @SeanCline unfortunately I'm using C++11 so I can't use GSL, but nevertheless it's a nice way of doing it. So Mb I'm going to implement `gsl/span` with C++11. If you want you can post the answer and I will accept it.

Comment: In case you're still interested, there is the [gsl-lite](https://github.com/martinmoene/gsl-lite) project, which backports many features of the gsl to older compilers.

Comment: @SeanCline Nice, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting `YSC`s comment in order to answer this question:

> They discourage pointer arithmetic for "standard" operations. Dealing
>   with uninitialized storage allocation is not. IMO, pointer arithmetic
>   in an allocator's allocate function is perfectly fine if its simple to
>   read.